# Cassandra primary key and clustering column design

Tags: cassandra

I want to create a Cassandra table. I know which my columns will be. I also know what the queries will be. I have to decide which of them to make the partition key, which to make clustering columns and which ordinary columns. Is there any resource which can guide me into making this efficient?

Thanks,

Serban

Comment: Asking us to recommend an off-site resource is considered off-topic, so I'm voting to close.  What you might want to try, is editing your question with your current table layout, the queries you need to serve, and anything that you might have tried so far.  But as it stands, this isn't a good question for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to start thinking about your primary keys by reading [Patrick's guide at Planet Cassandra](http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/the-most-important-thing-to-know-in-cassandra-data-modeling-the-primary-key/). There are also tons of resources at the [DataStax Academy](https://academy.datastax.com).